# Construct the equation of a linear vector field if the phase portrait is given

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

[image: Vector Field]

I already know that since that $0$ is a repulsor singular point over $x$-axis and $-x$ also  works as a repulsor point in opposite direction. Can anyone help me out by finding  the equation of this vector field given the phase portrait on picture? Thanks.

Comment: There seem to be more information given on the paper. Could you provide also that information. It seems that the arrows are vertical at $y=-\mu x$, is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the matrix of this vector field, so 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{bmatrix}
= A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
$$
There isn't enough on the photograph to tell so let me make some additional assumptions.

1. $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  If that's not true, $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is at least a positive multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, but let's keep it simple.
2. $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -\mu \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$.  Again, this is from the picture, modulo positive multiples.

If that's true then
\begin{align*}
A \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} 
&= A \left(\begin{bmatrix} -1/\mu \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1/\mu \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right)\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1/\mu \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1/\mu \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} 
 = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\mu \\ 1/\mu \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
So from this we know that
$$
    A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1/\mu \\ 0 & 1/\mu \end{bmatrix}
$$